# How can we install Husky Simulator in melodic ditro?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I was going through link:
http://wiki.ros.org/husky_gazebo/Tutorials/Simulating%20Husky

In the command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-husky-simulator
```

I replaced <*distro*> with *melodic*

But I am getting following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-husky-package
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292964/how-can-we-install-husky-simulator-in-melodic-ditro?/) by [Swag10](https://answers.ros.org/users/35462/swag10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you visit http://wiki.ros.org/husky_gazebo you'll see that this package is currently only released on Indigo and Kinetic (notice the blue boxes at the top of the wiki page). This is why you cannot install from `apt-get`.

You can certainly try to build this package from source, but you are not guaranteed that it will work.

To give some confidence that it might work, I just tried to compile `husky` package on ROS Melodic, and was able to compile with almost no issues (although I haven't tested it extensively). A few notes:

- I was able to install many dependencies from `apt-get`.
- The only packages I had to build from source in order to launch the `husky_playpen.launch` file were:

  - LMS1xx
  - husky
  - interactive_marker_twist_server
  - robot_localization
  - twist_mux
- The only issue I had compiling was with LMS1xx as described [here](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/LMS1xx/issues/49). Following the instructions on [this ros-overlay bug report](https://github.com/ros/ros-overlay/issues/509) I was able to switch all `logXXXX` calls to `CONSOLE_BRIDGE_logXXXX` using a couple of `sed` commands.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Swag10](https://answers.ros.org/users/35462/swag10/) on 2018-06-04**:
Thank you for the clarification.
Instead of melodic I am working with Kinetic now.